# How could I insert a statement before try statement in method using github.parser

Tags: javaparser

I am using Com.GitHub.java parser for generating java code. i am facing a problem . problem is :

I have need bellow output . This line "`String result = null;`" need to show before `try` statement .
But it is showing inside of try statement.

**My Source code:**
https://pastebin.mozilla.org/McXbnU7w

**Maven dependency:**

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.javaparser/javaparser-core -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.javaparser</groupId>
  <artifactId>javaparser-core</artifactId>
  <version>3.24.4</version>
</dependency>
```

**Expected output of my code:**

```
public Response saveProduct(ProductDto productDto) throws ServletException, IOException {
String result = null;
try {
createMyProduct.setProduct(productDto.getProduct());
createMyProduct.execute(parameterMap);
result = createMyProduct.getResult();

    } catch (BusinessException e) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(result).build();
    }
```

Comment: Add code as text not as image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add as many blocks as you need. E.g. `String result = null` should be treated as a separate block and `try` block should be another block. You cannot shove all statements in one block. Also in `addingException` method, you are adding `try` block into another `BlockStmt`. That is not needed. It will put extra curly braces.
Here is updated code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import com.github.javaparser.ast.CompilationUnit;
import com.github.javaparser.ast.Modifier;
import com.github.javaparser.ast.NodeList;
import com.github.javaparser.ast.body.ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration;
import com.github.javaparser.ast.body.MethodDeclaration;
import com.github.javaparser.ast.body.Parameter;
import com.github.javaparser.ast.expr.MethodCallExpr;
import com.github.javaparser.ast.expr.NameExpr;
import com.github.javaparser.ast.expr.StringLiteralExpr;
import com.github.javaparser.ast.stmt.BlockStmt;
import com.github.javaparser.ast.stmt.CatchClause;
import com.github.javaparser.ast.stmt.EmptyStmt;
import com.github.javaparser.ast.stmt.ExpressionStmt;
import com.github.javaparser.ast.stmt.ReturnStmt;
import com.github.javaparser.ast.stmt.Statement;
import com.github.javaparser.ast.stmt.TryStmt;
import com.github.javaparser.ast.type.ClassOrInterfaceType;

public class ProductCreate2 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    CompilationUnit compilationUnit = new CompilationUnit();
    compilationUnit.setPackageDeclaration("org.meveo.mymodule.resource");
    compilationUnit.addImport("java.util", false, true);

    ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration restEndpointClass = compilationUnit.addClass("ProductCreate",Modifier.Keyword.PUBLIC);
    restEndpointClass.addField("CreateMyProduct", "createMyProduct", Modifier.Keyword.PRIVATE);

    NodeList<ClassOrInterfaceType> extendsList = new NodeList<>();
    extendsList.add(new ClassOrInterfaceType("CustomEndpointResource"));
    restEndpointClass.setExtendedTypes(extendsList);

    MethodDeclaration restMethod = restEndpointClass.addMethod("saveProduct", Modifier.Keyword.PUBLIC);
    restMethod.addParameter("ProductDto", "productDto");
    restMethod.setType("Response");
    restMethod.addAndGetAnnotation("POST");
    restMethod.addThrownException(IOException.class);
    //restMethod.addThrownException(ServletException.class);
    //restMethod.getBody().get().getStatements().add(new ExpressionStmt(new NameExpr("String result = null")));
    //restMethod.createBody().addStatement(new ExpressionStmt(new NameExpr("String result = // null")));
        


    BlockStmt blockStmt = new BlockStmt();


    blockStmt.addStatement(new ExpressionStmt(new NameExpr("String result = null")));

    BlockStmt blockStmt1 = new BlockStmt();
    blockStmt1.addStatement(new MethodCallExpr(new NameExpr("createMyProduct"), "setProduct").addArgument("productDto.getProduct()"));
    blockStmt1.addStatement(new MethodCallExpr(new NameExpr("createMyProduct"), "init").addArgument("parameterMap"));
    blockStmt1.addStatement(new MethodCallExpr(new NameExpr("createMyProduct"), "execute").addArgument("parameterMap"));
    blockStmt1.addStatement(new MethodCallExpr(new NameExpr("createMyProduct"), "finalize").addArgument("parameterMap"));
    blockStmt1.addStatement(new MethodCallExpr(new NameExpr("createMyProduct"), "getResult()"));

    Statement blockStmt2 =addingException(blockStmt1);
    blockStmt.addStatement(blockStmt2);

    restMethod.setBody(blockStmt);

    restMethod.getBody().get().getStatements().add(new ReturnStmt(new NameExpr("Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(result).build()")));

    System.out.println(compilationUnit);

  }

  private static Statement addingException(BlockStmt body) {
    TryStmt ts = new TryStmt();
    ts.setTryBlock(body);
    CatchClause cc = new CatchClause();
    String exceptionName = "e";
    cc.setParameter(new Parameter().setName(exceptionName).setType(Exception.class));
    BlockStmt cb = new BlockStmt();
    cb.addStatement(new ExpressionStmt(new NameExpr("return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(result).build()")));
    // cb.addStatement(new ThrowStmt(new NameExpr(exceptionName)));
    cc.setBody(cb);
    ts.setCatchClauses(new NodeList<>(cc));
    return ts;
  }

}
```

Comment: thanks your solution , it is working partially . but got  another problem : Problem : After executing your solution  i got a additional bracket { after "String result = null;" line. How to can i avoid this unexpected  {}  bracket.        my problematic output is : https://pastebin.mozilla.org/GFAmSa96

Comment: ah alright I did not notice. Actually you were wrapping the `TryStmt` in another `BlockStmt`. Why don't you just return `TryStmt` without wrapping it. I have updated my answer doing the same.

Comment: ah got it the cause of this { issue. I understand that i have to return TryStmt without wrapping it.
But How can i do this .

TryStmt ts = new TryStmt();
ts.setTryBlock(body); can you please give me idea

Comment: i am facing another problem in this class . How can i add @AutoWired  annotation in class'es field level .  https://pastebin.mozilla.org/XYvmeD1r

Comment: @GulamSamdani That is a different question. Please post it as a different question.. And share the question link here. I'll check if I find something...

Comment: i have create a new question .                                                              https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73561220/how-could-i-inherit-a-class-using-github-parser-without-deprication-warrings . 
@Syed Aqeel Ashiq